# To give two array values from controler to my view page

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

give two array values from controler to my view page

```
    $data2=$this->input->POST();

    if($this->quiz_mod->login($data2))
    {
    $qus= $this->quiz_mod->get_data();
    $ans= $this->quiz_mod->get_data2();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $data2=$this->input->POST();

if($this->quiz_mod->login($data2))
{

$qus= $this->quiz_mod->get_data();
$ans= $this->quiz_mod->get_data2();

$data['qus'] = $qus;
$data['ans'] = $ans;

$this->load->view('VIEW_NAME_HERE',$data);
// in view get data in these array $qus and $ans 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is if you want to pass more than one array to view then you should do something like this in controller

```
$data=array();
$data['qus']=$this->model_name->function_name(); // query for qus
$data['ans']=$this->model_name->function_name(); // query for ans
$this->load->view('view_name',$data);
```